# Can I get value from variable whose value is stored in another variable?

Tags: variables, jmeter, beanshell

In JDBC PreProcessor I get records from database and assume that one of column is saved to variable "DESCRIPTION"

In BeanShell PreProcessor I do something like this:

```
String descriptionFirstResult ="DESCRIPTION_"+number
```

to get specific number of row and then I save this result to vars.

```
vars.put("DescriptionFirstResult",descriptionFirstResult);
```

At the end I want to check if value from database is the same as value from response and in Response Assertion I do:

Text Response -> Substring

```
"description": "${${DescriptionFirstResult}}"
```

And I get
Assertion failure message: Test failed: text expected to contain /"description": ${${DescriptionFirstResult}}/

Why is it wrong and what should I change to get correct result?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at jmeter functions. `__V` let you evaluate variable names. In your case it could look like this:

```
"description": "${__V(${DescriptionFirstResult})}"
```

If the value of `${DescriptionFirstResult}` equals "D1" this function would look for a variable `D1` and return the value of `D1` as the result.

Comment: It's still problem with assertion result. 
Assertion failure message: Test failed: text expected to contain /"description": "${DescriptionFirstResult}",/

Comment: So I assume you have the following setup:  a sampler where you want to assert that the response contains an expected text **and** a pre jdbc pre-processor where you get the input for the assertion **and** a reponse assertion where compare those values. If the jdbc pre-processor uses sql like `select description from my_table_`  in a way that required description is always the first record of the result then you just have to put  **description** into the variable field of the jdbc pre-processor. That way you just have to add ${description_1}  to the response assertion.